Tikz externalize doesn't work in overleaf with LuaLatex
I have a big project with multiple folders and files in overleaf and I want to externalize my tikz figs. I have followed this tutorial but this doesn't work. I get the following error for all the figs

Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'lualatex -shell-escape
-halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "./tikz/output-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{output}\input{output}"' did NOT result in a
usable output file './tikz/output-figure0' (expected one of
.pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you have enabled system
calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is
also named 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the command
simply failed? Error messages can be found in
'./tikz/output-figure0.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to typeset
the picture.

In my main.tex I have added
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=./tikz/]

and created a folder tikz with an empty foo.tex file (as indicated in the tuto). I have also tried to add a latexmkrc file with
$lualatex = 'lualatex --shell-escape';

but this didn't work. I found a post which suggested to add \usepackage{shellesc} but this didn't change anything.
There are no compilation errors if I remove \tikzexternalize.
Any help would be appreciated.
EDIT : Here a simple example that reproduces the problem.
My main.tex is of the form
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}

\input{package.tex}

\begin{document}
\input{Chap/chap.tex}
\end{document}

with package.tex
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=./tikz/]

\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

and chap.tex
\begin{figure}
    \centering
\feynmandiagram [inline=(b.base), horizontal=b to a] {
a -- [scalar,  momentum=\(p'-p\) ]b[blob, label = \(\Gamma\)],
c -- [fermion, edge label=\(p\)] b -- [fermion, edge label=\(p'\)] d,
};
= 
\feynmandiagram [inline=(b.base), horizontal=b to a] {
a -- [scalar,  momentum=\(p'-p\) ]b[crossed dot, label = \(\gamma\)],
c -- [fermion, edge label=\(p\)] b -- [fermion, edge label=\(p'\)] d,
}; +
\feynmandiagram [inline=(b.base), horizontal=b to a] {
a -- [scalar, momentum=\(p'-p\) ]b[blob, label = \(\Gamma\)],
c -- [anti fermion,edge label=\(p'\)]d -- [anti fermion] b -- [anti fermion] e -- [anti fermion,edge label=\(p\)] f,
e -- [photon, momentum=\(k\)]d,
};  
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:label}
\end{figure}

I just found that if I copy/past package.tex inside the main.tex (so without the input), externalize works. BUT it works only with this simple example, not with my full project which is weird.
EDIT 2 SOLUTION:
I have a \includepdfin my main.tex so I had to change
\tikzexternalize[prefix=./tikz/,optimize command away=\includepdf]

It seems very important to put this last command directly in main.tex and not in an external file. Also import pdfpages BEFORE using tikzexternalize.

Welcome! Can you provide code for a minimal document which we can compile to reproduce the problem? Did you look in the log file referred to in the error message? Note also that the external library is basically unmaintained. In general, it will fail for some pictures. Depending on what exactly your pictures include, it might fail for all of them if, say, they all make use of a common element which is problematic. You shouldn't need to add --shell-escape in Overleaf. Overleaf already adds suitable options. However, use of different directories for input files might be problematic.

I have added an example. I have also found a solution within this simple example, which doesn't work for the full project (see end of the edit).

What happens if chap.tex is in the top level directory rather than a sub-directory? I don't understand why copy-pasting the contents of package.tex would alter things .... externalize is very odd .... I would suggest using memoize but, unfortunately, Overleaf doesn't have it. (Or didn't.)

With the \inpute{package} and chap.tex in top level this doesn't work. Edit: memoize not available in overleaf.

Do you mean \input{package}? By the way, you should not use fontenc with LuaTeX. Optimising \includepdf away shouldn't make any difference except it is more efficient not to bother with something you don't need when externalising. There's no logic to what you say does and doesn't work. It isn't that I don't believe you because I've seen the external library behave in weird ways for me, too. It's just I don't have any idea what to suggest.

Yes\input{package}, it was a typo.
It's quite possible that there's no logic to it, but it works. I really just put \tikzexternalize[prefix=./tikz/,optimize command away=\includepdf] in my main.tex and the problem was solved. It was pure serendipity.
Concerning fontenc, if I don't use it I get this message Unknown Operator Encoding and the document doesn't display correctly. I prefer to keep it.

Try fontspec instead.
